# Can high number of warnings cause a SSIS package to fail/cancelled?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have an SSIS package that has a large number of warnings displayed in the output window. For eg:

> Warning: 0x800470C8 at Import 9) Shift Qty, Excel Source [17]: The
> external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with the
> data source columns. The external column "F2" needs to be updated. 
> Warning: 0x800470C8 at Import 15) Max resource Qty, Excel Source [17]:
> The external columns for Excel Source are out of synchronization with
> the data source columns. The external column "F2" needs to be updated.

Now, since this is part of a for each loop container, the number of warnings can increase when more files will be added to this process?

Is this something I should be worried about? Can this cause the SSIS package to fail?

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't be anything to be worried about. Warnings are just that - warnings, so they are there to to notify you that there might be something wrong here.

The only thing they do is build up more rows to SSISDB (if you deploy the package to SQL Server SSISDB), but it will take a while for that to get too large (make sure the retention time hasn't been left to something like 365 days so that SSISDB clears the logs in timely manner).